# How to add a continuous sine wave mask to an image iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, animation

I am trying to create a loader framework which will almost look like this.
But I don't have much info about how to do this. Creating a sine wave using `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer` is possible. But How can I create a continuous sine wave like this? Also how to use this as a mask?

Any hint will be a great help.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Comment: You can check this link may be you will help this demo link: https://github.com/poolqf/FillableLoaders

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest let designer create flash file and then convert flash into multiple images. Once you have multiple images, use below lib to show animation as loader.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tsactivityindicatorview

This is what I do in multiple projects.